# Why are my CSS animations consuming so many resources?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have realized that CSS animations with keyframes are really hungry for resources.

I've already eliminated the shadows, which increased performance by almost 50% in my case. I've also heard that I should include a `rotateZ(360deg)` to trick the browser into using GPU acceleration. But even with those "tricks" applied, my star background is really resource-hungry. As soon as you open my website, CPU and GPU usage goes up drastically and remains at a pretty high level.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to perform my desired animation without wasting so much CPU or GPU power.

I wanted a background of moving stars on my website. My solution to this was to create a div for each star, giving it a size, background colour and CSS animation with keyframes. The opacity, x and y position, as well as the speed of the animation are randomized.

The keyframes are the following:

```
@keyframes linear-translate {
  0% {
    left: -10%;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg); /* rotateZ tricks the browser to use GPU acceleration for better performance  */
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

@keyframes linear-translate-initial {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}
```

Here is an example for one of the div elements (with tailwind CSS classes):

```
<div class="absolute block bg-gray-200 rounded-full" 
     style="left: 1%; top: 8%; width: 3px; height: 3px; opacity: 0.381289; 
     animation: 90.0069s linear 0s 1 normal none running linear-translate-initial, 
     110.007s linear 90.0069s infinite normal none running linear-translate;"></div>
```

Link to codesandbox with a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/starbackgroundreacttailwindcss-wzers?file=/src/Starfield.tsx

Any ideas on why those animations are consuming so much power and on how to make them more efficient? It's just a horizontal translation after all...

**Update:**

I tried to layer the stars in div elements of different speeds as suggested by Marco.
My result can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/layeredstarbackgroundreacttailwindcss-wj71q?file=/src/App.tsx:392-445

Unfortunately, the "improvement" is not that great. The CPU usage went a little down, but the GPU usage increased drastically.

Comment: You probably want to look at [Particles.js](https://github.com/Wufe/react-particles-js). As using `canvas` is the best approach to deal with big number of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around a bit with your sandbox and yes the solution is that simple - there are just to many / different animations / items to handle for the CPU you can see that easily when opening the task manager and checkout the CPU usage while the sandbox is idle with your page. On my "small" machine Firefox uses up to 53% CPU. when i decrease the amount of stars in your script (down to 10) it goes down to around 18%.

I had a similar problem with a "moving div" background with shadows / gradient colors and rotations while moving from left to right...

Interesting project so far.
An idea might be to have a limited amount of layers with multiple stars fixed there and then to move the whole layer (even if you have 10 layers then there are just 10 objects that moves)...

Yes you will not have the same strong effect like calculating / moving each star by its own but with 10 layers as a background (i think its a Background right?) it should not make any markable difference to the viewer...

Comment: I thought of this idea with multiple layers as well. I just didn't have time to figure out the details yet, because I would like to have a continuous animation (it shouldn't make a jump each time the animation is repeated). On top of that, the height of the website might change (e.g. expandable div elements). Changes in size should also not cause those "jumps" of stars. But it would be possible to implement your suggestion. Fewer objects being animated = less CPU / GPU usage

Comment: I tried your suggestion of layering the stars and only animating the div that contains the stars. My result can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/layeredstarbackgroundreacttailwindcss-wj71q?file=/src/App.tsx:392-445

Unfortunately, the "improvement" is not that great. The CPU usage went a little down, but the GPU usage increased drastically.